# Moving Delete icon on UITableView in 'grouped' style into the cell?

Tags: uitableview, coding-style

I have a UITableView style set to grouped.  This works correctly except when in edit mode the 'minus' icon for Deleting a cell isn't within the cell.  It's to the left.   In the Weather App that icon is in the cell.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Image here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had a hard time finding the solution to this, so I figured I'd post it:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. It looks like Weather uses a plain table view with its corners rounded, not a grouped table view. But I'd you mist have this behavior, try changing the size of the cell's background view when it's editing...